# Jaspert report get data from provider with web service. How to?

Tags: web-services, jasper-reports

There is system, that has data, and can provide it's data with web-services (for example Lotus Notes database). Can Jasper get data for it's report by calling web-service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but it will probably get very complicated very quickly. But if you want to travel that path, it is definitely possible with a [JRXmlDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRXmlDataSource.html). You will have to define the datasource like:

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource(
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.getLocationInputStream("http://yourserver.com/xml_data_source")
```

See [this](http://blog.altosresearch.com/use-xml-data-source-for-chart-generation-in-jasperreports/) post, where someone seems to have embarked on a similar quest, to retrieve xml data from a remote server for the report.

That being said, it will probably be a lot less work, and your code will probably be a lot more maintainable if you fetch the data from the server in your code, select the fields you want for your report and pass it in as, say, a JRMapCollection datasource, especially if the remote service offers a wsdl against which you could generate a client using a tool like Apache Axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom DataSource by implementing the interface [JRDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRDataSource.html).

Full explanation: http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#customdatasource.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution right now is to use Jasper data source SPI to make your Restful services as data source just like JDBC data sources.

http://javattitude.com/2015/07/30/using-rest-web-service-as-data-source-for-jasper-reports/

One written this will work for all you services since this is generic.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using Web Service Datasource

http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source

This Community project implement a Custom Datasource, built using the latest Custom Datasource framework (leveraging Data Adapters internally).

It is also working inside JasperReports Server:

You can use it to fill Query based Input Controls, as well as Ad Hoc Reporting (for Commercial version) using it through Topic.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide additional details?